# Process.Start() does nothing when called from a C# written service

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I have created a service that works good, except for this section that don't do what I want

```
shutdownProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
shutdownProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Siemens\Automation\WinCC RT Advanced";
shutdownProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Siemens\Automation\HmiRtmShutdown.exe";
shutdownProcess.Start();

string errors = shutdownProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
eventLog1.WriteEntry(errors, EventLogEntryType.Error, eventId++);
```

The problem is that the process is not executed;
as you can see I tried to record errors in a log, but the log records a empty string so it seems that there is no error;

This application works perfectly when I call it from cmd.exe; I also tried to use process.start() with cmd.exe passing the path as argument, but it did not work;
I installed the service as LocalSystem to give it maximum privileges;
I also tried to put the service into same folder and call only the .exe to exclude errors in writing the path; nothing

please help!

Comment: Are you sure the called process is _happy_ to be executed in session 0 without any interactive UI? Also be sure to set `UseShellExecute` to `false` and `CreateNoWindow` to `true`.

Comment: Hi thank you; The called process is used to close a siemens application and does not have UI; what about session?

Comment: Attach the VS debugger to the service process (Debug, Attach to Process), and put a breakpoint on the Process.Start. This will help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: Starting from Vista (if I remember correctly, not sure) Services run on a separate non-interactive session (0) and your user applications run on separate sessions (for example session 1 for first logged in user). If called process does interacts with an application in session 1 using, for example, messages and/or simulating user input then it won't work (because **sessions are isolated**). When installing a service there is an option to enable "allow service to interact with desktop". However...it's mostly for compatibility, not such good practice.

Comment: Hello, really thanks, I tried to enable this option but it took no effect

Comment: Then, if "allow service to interact with desktop" for a local system account is enabled, if CreateNoWindow is true, if UseShellExecute is false and the other program does not work as expected then...you're probably out of luck. You can, however, start a scheduled operation (there are libraries for this to make it easy specifically from services) which will run then in the user interactive session (and then it should work as expected).

Comment: Side note: Event IDs are meant to be *stable* application specific identifiers that help people work out what type of thing happened (without having to parse the *text* of the event, especially bad if localization has been applied). An incrementing number doesn't fit the bill.

Comment: Thanks Damien , this was so interesting; i did it in this case to track the timer thickes in my service and try to understand the behaviour, i'll not do it in the future

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute applications or executables which try to render a User Interface or are designed to require interactive login from a Windows Service which runs in background in  UI less mode ( Session 0 from Vista onwards as others have comemnted ).

try to wite some unit tests and run your code from the unit tests in Visual Studio, if all works fine but then from the Windows Service does not work, then the problem is exactly the one explained above.

Comment: thank you; i am pretty sure this is the problem, there is a workaround to do the job by the service?